Verilog set bit counter
I'm trying to create a Verilog program that would display the digit with greater number of bits set. The code is working. However, it counts the bits from the previous values instead of its current value.
module compare_numbers(A,countA, B, countB, greaterA, greaterB, equalAB);
  input [7:0] A, B;
  output greaterA, greaterB, equalAB;
  output reg [7:0] countA, countB;
 
  integer i, j;
 
  
  always@(A)
    begin
      countA=0;
      for (i=0; i<9; i=i+1)
        if (A[i] == 1'b1)
          countA = countA + 1;
    end
 
  always@(B)
    begin
      countB=0;
      for (j=0; j<9; j=j+1)
        if (B[j] == 1'b1)
          countB = countB + 1;
      
    end 
  assign greaterA = (countA > countB);
  assign greaterB = (countA < countB);
  assign equalAB = (countA==countB);
endmodule

module tb;

    // Inputs
  reg [7:0] A, B;
  reg [255:0] string1;
 

    // Outputs
  wire greaterA, greaterB, equalAB;
  wire [7:0] countA, countB;
 
 
  compare_numbers tb(A,countA, B, countB, greaterA, greaterB, equalAB);
 
    initial fork
      $display("A\t\tB\t\tA no. of set bits\tB no. of set bits\tWhich has more bits set?");
      $monitor("%b\t%b\t%d\t\t\t%d\t%s",A, B, countA, countB, string1);
    join

    initial begin
     
        #1 A=8'b00001000; B=8'b11111110;
        if (greaterA==1) string1="Binary Digit A";
        else if (greaterB==1) string1="Binary Digit B";
        else string1="Equal digits";
     
        #3 A=8'b10001100; B=8'b10001100;
        if (greaterA==1) string1="Binary Digit A";
        else if (greaterB==1) string1="Binary Digit B";
        else string1="Equal digits";
     
        #5 A=8'b10101010; B=8'b00011000;
        if (greaterA==1) string1="Binary Digit A";
        else if (greaterB==1) string1="Binary Digit B";
        else string1="Equal digits";
     
    end



The problem is due to a Verilog simulation race condition.  You are trying to display values as they are changing.  One solution is to add delays between when the signals change and when you call $monitor.
Here is a modified version of the testbench which calls $display when all the signals are stable.  It adds a #1 delay before it sets string, then adds another #1 delay before it displays all the values:
module tb;

    // Inputs
  reg [7:0] A, B;
  reg [255:0] string1; 

    // Outputs
  wire greaterA, greaterB, equalAB;
  wire [7:0] countA, countB;     
 
  compare_numbers tb(A,countA, B, countB, greaterA, greaterB, equalAB);
 
    initial begin
        $display("A\t\tB\t\tA no. of set bits\tB no. of set bits\tWhich has more bits set?");
     
        #1 A=8'b00001000; B=8'b11111110; #1;
        if      (greaterA==1) string1="Binary Digit A";
        else if (greaterB==1) string1="Binary Digit B";
        else                  string1="Equal digits";
        print();
     
        #3 A=8'b10001100; B=8'b10001100; #1;
        if (greaterA==1) string1="Binary Digit A";
        else if (greaterB==1) string1="Binary Digit B";
        else string1="Equal digits";
        print();

        #5 A=8'b10101010; B=8'b00011000; #1;
        if (greaterA==1) string1="Binary Digit A";
        else if (greaterB==1) string1="Binary Digit B";
        else string1="Equal digits";
        print();

    end

    task print;
        #1;
        $display("%b\t%b\t%d\t\t\t%d\t%s",A, B, countA, countB, string1,,$time);
        #1;
    endtask

endmodule

Output:
A       B       A no. of set bits   B no. of set bits   Which has more bits set?
00001000    11111110      1           7                   Binary Digit B                    3
10001100    10001100      3           3                     Equal digits                    9
10101010    00011000      4           2                   Binary Digit A                   17

Note that the code also displays the simulation time using $time.  This is very useful for debug.

thank you so much!

@PaulaBiancaPascual: You're welcome.  You can go ahead and Accept
the answer.
